# Using sudo over ssh: sudo command not found

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I am trying to run a command on a remote server as the superuser through `ssh`. For that, I pass the command with `ssh -t` from macOS as follows:

```
bash-5.2$ ssh -t user@server.com "sudo echo Hi"
```

I get the password prompt for logging in to the server, but then instead of the password prompt for sudo I get the following error (no matter which command I use with sudo):

```
bash: line 1: sudo: command not found
Connection to server.com closed.
```

I don't understand why this happens. When I login to the server and run the command on it separately, it works fine. So this works:

```
bash-5.2$ ssh user@server.com
... Password: 
Last login: ...
bash-5.1$ sudo echo hi
Password:
Last login: ...
hi
```

I am quite new to this so I may be overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If `sudo` is installed, probably not in your path.

See if `sudo` is your path by running `which sudo` or `echo $PATH`. If sudo is not in your path, your path variable might be broken. You can try testing this by executing a common location for `sudo /usr/bin/sudo` or running `locate sudo | grep bin` to attempt to find its location.

Comment: [Why not use `which`? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/108618)

Comment: ...Or, since `sudo` works when he logs in to the server, as you said, just use the output of `which sudo` as the full path, without guessing and without `locate`.

Comment: On the remote server, the sudo program is located in `/usr/local/bin` which is indeed present in the `PATH` environment variable. I have verified that this works correctly: `ssh -t user@server.com "PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH && sudo echo Hi"` but I don't understand why I need to update `PATH` when sudo is present in `PATH` when I login to ther server.

Comment: I guess I should set `PATH=/usr/local/bin:\$PATH` otherwise the command substitutes the client's $PATH value.

Comment: Has you setted the `PATH` on the server in `~/.ssh/environment` (needs to be enabled by `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in `sshd_config`)? Maybe, enabling `PermitUserEnvironment yes` is enough.